# Chaining string.replace in F#

Tags: f#

I have a string with some tokens in it like this:

```
"There are two things to be replaced.  {Thing1} and {Thing2}"
```

I want to replace each token with different values so the final result looks like this:

```
"There are two things to be replaced.  Don and Jon"
```

I created a function that chains String.Replace like this

```
let doReplacement (message:string) (thing1:string) (thing2:string) =
    message.Replace("{Thing1}", thing1).Replace("{Thing2}", thing2)
```

the problem is that when I chain .Replace, the values have to stay on the same line.  Doing this does not work:

```
let doReplacement (message:string) (thing1:string) (thing2:string) =
    message
    .Replace("{Thing1}", thing1)
    .Replace("{Thing2}", thing2)
```

To allow me to do a multi-line chain, I was thinking of something like this:

```
message
|> replaceString "{Thing1}" thing1
|> replaceString "{Thing2}" thing2
```

with a supporting function like this:

```
let replaceString (message:string) (oldValue:string) (newValue:string) =
    message.Replace(oldValue, newValue)
```

However, that does not work.  Is there another way to handle the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It compiles if you indent the method calls:

```
let doReplacement (message:string) (thing1:string) (thing2:string) =
    message
        .Replace("{Thing1}", thing1)
        .Replace("{Thing2}", thing2)
```

This is a style I have often seen in C# and it seems pretty logical to me.

Comment: I would put `message` at the end of the parameter list here.  That would be more idiomatic for F# (most significant parameter at the end), and would enable pipelining of `doReplacement` if desired.

Answer (score 7):

By using `|>` the piped value is send to the rightmost unbound parameter (value piped by `|>` is send to thing2).
By reversing the order of parameters it works as expected.

```
let replaceString (oldValue:string) (newValue:string) (message:string) =
    message.Replace(oldValue, newValue)

let message = "There are two things to be replaced.  {Thing1} and {Thing2}"
let thing1 = "Don"
let thing2 = "Jon"

message
|> replaceString "{Thing1}" thing1
|> replaceString "{Thing2}" thing2
|> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: I usually do it this way, though I have put the function in a common library under the `String` module, so it's just `String.replace`.  The library is available as CurryOn.Common on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CurryOn.Common/0.1.2) and [GitHub](https://github.com/CurryOnCoders/CurryOn/tree/master/CurryOn.Common).

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this with a fold (though requires input in a list/map. More useful if you have consistent substitutions you're making, which might not be the case for you)

```
let replacements =
    [ "{thing1}", "Don"
      "{thing2}", "Jon" ]

let replaceString (input: string) : string = 
    replacements 
    |> List.fold (fun acc (oldText, newText) -> acc.Replace(oldText, newText)) input
```

Or a more general case, enter replacements as an argument (say a map this time)

```
let replaceString (replaceMap: Map<string, string>) (input: string) : string =
    replaceMap
    |> Map.fold (fun acc oldText newText -> acc.Replace(oldText, newText)) input
```