# RProvider and R 4.0.0 display strange characters on dataframe columns

Tags: r, f#

I run a simple piece of code to fit a single line through points. [oversimplified LM of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm2RM.png)

Everything runs great, except the actual Print() of the linear model and the data frame contain  strange characters surrounding each column (byte order codes or encodings?  I'm not sure.).

Each column begins with the characters \002ÿþ.  Each column ends with the character \003ÿþ .   You can see how it displays in the console window here:
[Weird Characters RProvider and R 4.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAdqi.png)

The code is below.  You can create a simple F# console NET Core app, add the RProvider 2.1.0 nuget package and drop in the following code. I'm very rusty with programming and statistics, and I don't know a lot about pipes, encodings or similar matters.  I love the RProvider, but it is not clear where characters are getting changed.

```
open RProvider
open RProvider.``base``
open RProvider.stats
open RProvider.graphics


let ys = [ for y in (2000.0)..(0.5)..(2050.0)  ->                                 
                 let randomStuff = R.rnorm(1, 0.0, 20.0).GetValue<double>()
                 let pMaxRes = R.pmax(y - 2030.0, None, 0.0).GetValue<float>()
                 let extraSlopeStuff = 8.011 * pMaxRes
                 (
                      y + randomStuff + extraSlopeStuff
                 )
            ]
let xs = [-((double) ys.Length-1.0)..0.0] 
let dataset =                        
        [ "Y"  , ys ;
          "X1" , xs] 
            |> namedParams |> R.data_frame
let linearModel = R.lm (formula="Y~X1",data=dataset)
printfn "results: %A" (linearModel.Print())
R.plot(xs, ys  ) |> ignore
R.abline(linearModel) |> ignore
R.Sys_sleep(2) |> ignore
```

I expected the results to print in clean columns with no extra characters, similar to the tables I see when running analogous code in RStudio.

When I print lists, there is no problem.  When I print a dataframe or matrix, the columns get weird characters.

I tried an older versions of R (3.4.4, 3.6.1, 3.6.3), and the problem seemed to disappear. Versions of R 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2 all had the same problem with the extra characters.

A possible workaround  (using code from post [Chaining string.replace in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50907903/)) is to add this to top of script, or calling after Print()

```
|> cleanString
```

```
let replaceString (oldValue:string) (newValue:string) (message:string) =
    message.Replace(oldValue, newValue)

let startStringSpecialChar1 = "\002ÿþ"
let startStringSpecialChar2 = "\003ÿþ"

let cleanString str:string =
    str
    |>  replaceString startStringSpecialChar1 ""
    |>  replaceString startStringSpecialChar2 ""

fsi.AddPrinter ( fun (synexpr:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) -> synexpr.Print() |> cleanString)
```